# Is Ubuntu deactivating connected but not mounted HDD?

Tags: shell-script, ubuntu, mount, hard-disk, fdisk

I am currently working on a bash script which should mount a veracrypt encrypted hdd on sundays to run backups. Since I want to rotate between two different HDDs every week, I have to check whether /dev/sdb1 or /dev/sdc1 is currently connected to the device before it gets mounted by the script:

```
hdd_sdb1="$(fdisk -l | grep /dev/sdb1)"
hdd_sdc1="$(fdisk -l | grep /dev/sdc1)"
if [ -n "$hdd_sdb1" ]
then
    hdd_name=/dev/sdb1
fi

if [ -n "$hdd_sdc1" ]
then
    hdd_name=/dev/sdc1
fi
```

Last weekend I've just changed the variable in the script and the mount worked fine. This weekend, when the script was run, none of the above fdisk commands returned a line, so the if query wasn't working. Now I wonder if the operating system deactivates the hard disk after a while if it has not been mounted and if there is a way to deactivate this?

Comment: Do the disks show up if yu run `fdisk` interactively from the command line?

Comment: (hard disk) devices are dynamic. You can't rely on their value/direct name. Order could change upon reboot or replug. Use properties of the disks in /dev/disk/by-*/

Comment: @A.B Thanks for the information. I'll do that. But that was not  connected to the issue I am having, because I've checked the value again and for now, it is still the same.

Comment: @RudiC Yes, I see the disks when I use fdisk, but won't see them with df, unless I mount one of them. But I don't know why the hdd wasn't listed in the fdisk list yesterday, when the script was running. I've checked the log file of my script and the $hdd_name variable was empty, so I guess the hdd wasn't found by the fdisk command at this time.

Comment: Have the script list the entire `fdisk` output so you can see what it sees.

Comment: @RudiC I used the exact same command today as the script did and it returned the connected hdd. I was thinking that ubuntu somehow puts the hdd into some kind of power saving mode, because I wasn't using the device since friday and it wasn't mounted. Maybe I woke up the hdd by manually mounting/dismounting it this morning before I tried to use the fdisk command again, which returned the connected hdd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.

It wasn't because the hard drive wasn't mounted properly or it shut down, but because of the `fdisk` command. Since the script was executed with a cronjob and no user is logged in, `fdisk` does not return any output, so the variable always remains empty.

I now simply test if the file `sdb1` or `sdc1` is in the `/dev` folder and bypass the `fdisk` command.